# Java RMI connection to localhost at home network can't find correct remote module

Tags: java, registry, localhost, rmi

I have been working on this project where two modules on different machines need to be in communication through RMI.

I start both client and server modules on my laptop. RMI seems to work correctly when i am at work and connected to work network, but when i am home, connected to my home network it does not work. It says remote object could not be found.

Here is the method i use at CLIENT side to get the reference to remote object

```
public static MyRMIApp getRemoteApp() throws RemoteException, NotBoundException, AccessException {
    Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", 28999); // tried 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost here, still not working
    MyRMIApp app = (MyRMIApp) registry.lookup("COM");
    return app;
}
```

Digging up a bit with some debugging, when i check the object value returned from getRemoteApp method, it shows me the end point is 67.215.65.132. Which is openDNS i am using to connect to internet. Shouldn't that be 127.0.0.1 ?

Then i used my mobile internet and tried again. It seems to be working but end-point is not 127.0.0.1 again it is the address assigned to me, which is  192.168.x.x

So can anybody please tell me what is wrong i am doing here ? I really would appreciate the help.

Oh and this is the piece of code at SERVER side

```
//Somwhere up top
private final static MyRMIApp rmiApp = new RMIServer();

//Down below
MyRMIApp stub = (MyRMIApp) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(rmiApp, 0);
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(28999);
        registry.rebind("COM", stub);
```

Comment: I am not sure about but I would suggest you to try changing the port number to which the remote object is exported, as 0 is a well-known port number and some other service might already be listening on it. Just change it to something above 1023.

Comment: Ok, did as u suggested, tried with port 1112 but it is still the same. The value is

Proxy[MyRMIApp,RemoteObjectInvocationHandler[UnicastRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[67.215.65.132:1112](remote),objID:[2723e75d:1357d203dd7:-7fff, -8442143534524841902]]]]]

Naturally the exception is:

    Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 67.215.65.132; nested exception is:

Comment: Can you please send me complete source. I would like to debug it myself.Also I found this link where people seem to be discussing the same problem as you have : http://www.coderanch.com/t/487650/java/java/java-rmi-ConnectException-Connection-refused. However I didn't see any solution. You might want to have a look.

Comment: Ok now i checked the link u gave me, i added -java.rmi.server.hostname=localhost to VM arguments. And it did get the end point correctly as localhost:53886 and the code works.

I checked about this rmi property java.rmi.server.hostname at the link   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi/javarmiproperties.html and it says by default rmi registry returns ip address assigned to me.

I understand why i get my ip address at other networks, but still don't get why i get openDNS at home network.

Now i am able to work at home lan.Still wondering why it does work like that

Comment: I am guessing that there might be a problem in how localhost is resolved to an ip address. It might be that the registry tries to resolve localhost using openDns but openDns is returning the ip of one of its own servers in instead of 127.0.0.1. Look at this thread related to this resolution problem , unrelated to rmi though -  http://forums.comcast.com/t5/Connectivity-and-Modem-Help/OpenDNS-Creates-problem-resolving-local-host-names/td-p/685736

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See item A.1 of the [RMI FAQ](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/faq.html): specifically, 'The appropriate workaround is to set the system property `java.rmi.server.hostname` when starting the server.'